# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

Why I am getting this error.
I am trying to map the response I get from the API *Get Request*.

This is my API Call :

```
export let CONTEXTROOT="http://localhost:8080/core/api/";
```

And this is my `getDashBoardData` Function :

```js
getDashBoardData(): Observable<string[]> {
     return this.http.get(CONTEXTROOT+'dashboard')
                     .map((res: Response) => res.json())
//                   .do(data => console.log('server data:', data))  // debug
                     .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

This is my error function , which will be called if error is there.

```js
 private handleError (error: any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
     let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                   error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
     console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
     return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

The functions were working correctly in Angular 2 , but in Angular 6 now we are facing many issues.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `map` and `do` ( ***RxJS 5.5 higher*** `do` -> `tap`) operators inside the `pipe` function.

If you are using `HttpClient` you also don't need to use `.json()` function.

```
return this.http.get(CONTEXTROOT+'dashboard')
                .pipe(
                      map((res: Response) => res.json()), // senseless if you are using `HttpClient`
                      tap(data => console.log('server data:', data)),
                      catchError(this.handleError)
                );
```

Comment: `do` is `tap` in rxjs 6

Comment: @TimMartens In higher than `RxJS 5.5`, which is added

Answer (score 1):

move it inside the `pipe` function along with the `do` operator. Also rename the `do` operator to `tap` because in new rxjs version they renamed it.

```
return this.http.get(CONTEXTROOT+'dashboard')  
                .pipe(
                   map((res: Response) => res.json()),
                   tap(data => console.log('server data:', data)),
                   catchError(this.handleError)
                 );
```

Comment: thanks for the help!! this is working but i still get the 404 bad request error.

Comment: it is working perfectly in POSTMAN , so that's what confuses me if , it is working in POSTMAN , how come it is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this map inside pipe

```
getDashBoardData(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get(CONTEXTROOT+'dashboard')    
        .pipe(
            .map((res: Response) => res.json()),
             catchError(this.handleError)
         );
}
```

Comment: with Angular4+, there is no need to do res.json(), which is what my colleagues have said. so I am looking for a solution where I don't want to use res.json().